# `using` an inner module with its symbol, in a nested structure of modules

Tags: module, julia, using

I have a nested structure of modules like this:

```
module TestMod
  module B
    export BB
    module BB

    end
  end
  module C
    module D
      #using ...B
      importall ...B 
      using BB # => ERROR: ArgumentError: Module BB not found in current path.
    end
  end
end
```

I want to do `using BB` in `module D` but it seems that the only way is to write a full path for `BB` (e.g. `using B.BB`), both `import` or `using` do not help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you've usinged `B`, you can do a relative import from the current module to any exported modules of `B`, including `BB`. See

```
julia> module TestMod
         module B
           export BB
           module BB
             x = 2
             export x
           end
         end
         module C
           module D
             using ...B 
             using .BB
             println(x)
           end
         end
       end
2
TestMod
```

The syntax `using .BB` means to use the module with name `BB` in the current module, whereas `using BB` means using top-level module `BB`; that is, it will look for `Main.BB`, which is not what you want.